# ios 7 SKScene size vs visible area?

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, sprite-kit

Apple's documentation has me a bit confused.

According to the documentation page : https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/GraphicsAnimation/Conceptual/SpriteKit_PG/Nodes/Nodes.html the relationship between the visible area of the scene in points and the size of the scene should be the same according to the sentence :

> "The size of the scene specifies the size of the visible portion of
>   the scene in points".

I created a custom scene that gets its size from the size of the device's screen (in my case I've been testing this for the iPad in portrait mode so the size should be 768 wide by 1024 high).

The following line which is being called in the scene's `createContent` method

```
NSLog(@"self.size : %f %f", self.size.width, self.size.height);
```

Returns

```
2014-07-15 14:53:28.844 SpriteWalkthrough[15888:90b] self.size : 768.000000 1024.000000
```

as expected.

However when I try to draw a SKSpriteNode at the position`(self.size.width/2,self.size.height/2)` the node is drawn in the upper right hand corner of the screen, not in the middle.

Why is this happening?

Comment: How are you adding the node to the scene?

Comment: I created a custom SKNode (called SpriteCar) with a SKSpriteNode property (which is a child of the SKNode). Within the scene's `contentCreated` method I used the line `[self addChild:self.sCar];`. The SpriteCar is also a property of the scene - I know I didn't have to do it this way but I'm just experimenting.

Comment: Try setting up the SpriteCar in `didMoveToView:` instead

Comment: @JuJoDi yeah I should have mentioned that....the `createContent` method is in `didMoveToView`

Comment: check the scene's scaleMode, try the other modes see if it makes any difference. Also verify that the coordinates are correct because 1024x768 is landscape but 768x1024 is portrait

Comment: @LearnCocos2D the scene's scale mode is SKSceneScaleModeAspectFill. I did try AspectFit as well but it didn't make any difference.

Also, I know that 768x1024 is portrait, I'm using that for now, also mentioned it in the question, so that part is working as expected.

Comment: It seems that I'm only seeing the bottom left quadrant of the entire scene.

Comment: You **have** to provide some code for context. This guessing is getting nowhere. Post how and where you launch the first scene and how you create and add the sprite.

Comment: @LearnCocos2D I found the bug. The problem was I had buried an extra line `self.sCar.car.position = self.sCar.postion;` because I was trying to figure out how children get their position with respect to their parents. I realize now that in the previous line where I had put `self.sCar.position = CGPointMake(self.size.width/2,self.size.height/2);` made the sCar's position in the mid point of the screen, but by making the car's position equal, it wasn't absolutely equivalent, only relative to sCar's - the moral of the story is that children's position is relative to their parent's in the scene!

Comment: The moral of the story is you gave us no ability to answer the question, and in many ways wasted everyone's time :)

Comment: @prototypical thanks for snarky comments made on the internet 3 hours after the fact :)

Comment: I apologize, however a question without proper context is a waste of anyone's time who tries to help you. 10 minutes or 3 hours, do you have any appreciation for their time ?  help them help you.

Comment: @prototypical understood, I didn't include it at first because I didn't want to overwhelm someone willing to help with a bunch of code pasted on a webpage. At first I thought it was my misinterpretation of Apple's documentation, and I didn't want someone to waste time wading through code that isn't their own.

Comment: I'd say that the code of the sprite and the node you are adding to would have been minimum context for such a question, and it's not a large chunk of code I'm guessing.  Sorry for the snarky comment, but coding charades is not the goal :)

Comment: @prototypical got it, I'll give more next time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For other people who may be making similar mistakes drawing SpriteNodes to a scene, take a look at my source code for the scene, and in particular pay attention to the `//self.sCar.car.position = self.sCar.position;`line.

FoolAroundScene.h

```
#import <SpriteKit/SpriteKit.h>

@interface FoolAroundScene : SKScene

@end
```

FoolAroundScene.m

```
#import "FoolAroundScene.h"
#import "ScrollingBackground.h"
#import "SpriteCar.h"

#define BACKGROUND_NAME @"clouds.jpg"



@interface FoolAroundScene ()
@property BOOL contentCreated;
@property (strong, nonatomic) ScrollingBackground * sbg;
@property (strong, nonatomic) SpriteCar * sCar;
@end

@implementation FoolAroundScene



-(void) didMoveToView:(SKView *)view
{
    if (!self.contentCreated) {

        [self createContent];
        self.contentCreated = !self.contentCreated;
    }
}

-(void)createContent
{
    self.sbg = [[ScrollingBackground alloc] initWithBackgroundImage:BACKGROUND_NAME size:self.size speed:2.0];
    self.sCar = [[SpriteCar alloc] init];

    [self addChild:self.sbg];
    [self addChild:self.sCar];
    self.sCar.position = CGPointMake(self.size.width/2, self.size.height/2);
    //self.sCar.car.position = self.sCar.position;

    SKSpriteNode * spriteCar = [self.sCar makeCarSprite];

    spriteCar.position = CGPointMake(CGRectGetMidX(self.frame), CGRectGetMidY(self.frame));


    NSLog(@"anchor point : %f %f", self.anchorPoint.x, self.anchorPoint.y);
    NSLog(@"self.size : %f %f", self.size.width, self.size.height);
    NSLog(@"self.scalemode : %d", self.scaleMode);

}

-(void) update:(NSTimeInterval)currentTime
{
    [self.sbg update:currentTime];

}

@end
```

Even though I had set the sCar's position property to the middle of the scene, by setting its child node (the sCar's car property) position to the same value, the child's position will not be the same as its parent's. This is because the child's position is *relative* to its parent's.

Explained another way : the parent's position in the context of the scene was (384,512) and the child's position in the context of its *parent* was (384,512). However this means that the child's position in the context of the scene was actually (768,1024), which is why the car was being drawn in the upper right hand corner of the screen.

Also, in case anyone wants the implementation for the sprite car, here it is. A crappily drawn car that can be used to get a grip on how the Sprite Kit works.

SpriteCar.h

```
#import <SpriteKit/SpriteKit.h>

@interface SpriteCar : SKNode
-(id)init;
-(SKSpriteNode *)makeCarSprite;

@end
```

SpriteCar.m

```
#import "SpriteCar.h"


@interface SpriteCar ()
@property (nonatomic, strong) SKSpriteNode * car;
@end

@implementation SpriteCar

-(id) init
{
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
        self.car = [self makeCarSprite];
        [self addChild:self.car];
    }

    return self;
}

-(SKSpriteNode *) makeCarSprite
{
    SKSpriteNode * carBody1 = [[SKSpriteNode alloc] initWithColor:[SKColor redColor] size:CGSizeMake(64.0, 24.0)];
    SKSpriteNode * carBody2 = [[SKSpriteNode alloc] initWithColor:[SKColor redColor] size:CGSizeMake(32.0, 32.0)];

    SKSpriteNode * wheel1 = [[SKSpriteNode alloc] initWithColor:[SKColor blackColor] size:CGSizeMake(8.0, 8.0)];

    SKSpriteNode * wheel2 = [wheel1 copy];


    SKSpriteNode * light = [[SKSpriteNode alloc] initWithColor:[SKColor yellowColor] size:CGSizeMake(6.0, 6.0)];


    carBody2.position = carBody1.position;
    wheel1.position = CGPointMake(30.0, -30);
    wheel2.position = CGPointMake(-30.0, -30.0);
    light.position = CGPointMake(32.0, 11.0);

    [carBody1 addChild:carBody2];
    [carBody1 addChild:wheel1];
    [carBody1 addChild:wheel2];
    [carBody1 addChild:light];

    SKAction * hover = [SKAction sequence:@[[SKAction moveByX:0.0 y:5.0 duration:0.1],
                                            [SKAction waitForDuration:0.05],
                                            [SKAction moveByX:0.0 y:-5.0 duration:0.1],
                                            [SKAction waitForDuration:0.05]]];

    [carBody1 runAction:[SKAction repeatActionForever:hover]];




    return carBody1;

}

@end
```

Comment: This is how mid point is calculated in the sample code when generating a new project: CGPoint(x:CGRectGetMidX(self.frame), y:CGRectGetMidY(self.frame));